# ffmpeg motion interpolation for 2x and 4x slowmotion

Tags: video, ffmpeg, interpolation, motion, slowmotion

I recently learn that I can use minterpolate option of ffmpeg for frame interpolation in a video. One of the configuration of this option is fps(frame per second) and I am not sure how I should set it to generate 2x and 4x slow-motion videos.
Here is how I use it right now:
ffmpeg -i input.avi  -filter "minterpolate='fps=120'" output.avi

seems like the generated output video doesn't have equal number of frames generated between every 2 consecutive frames.
Can anyone help me here or point me to a helpful document?

Thank you,

Comment: And what's the FPS of the input video? (hint: ffprobe)

Comment: I think it's 30 FPS. 
I got that by running this: ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=avg_frame_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.avi

Comment: did you already try this? https://lists.ffmpeg.org/mailman/listinfo/ffmpeg-user/

Comment: Have a look at this: https://superuser.com/questions/1005315/interpolation-with-ffmpeg/1568827#1568827

Answer (score 8):

You are currently generating a 120fps video at normal speed.
To do a slow-mo you need to slow it down by 4x
ffmpeg -i input.avi -filter "minterpolate='fps=120',setpts=4*PTS" output.avi

should do the trick.

Comment: This command will fail if you have an audio track on your input file, you'd have to use `-filter:v`